# using own icons in Panel or Page-Worker

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon-sdk

i want to use own icons in the Panel or the Page-Worker in the firefox-sdk. I want to load this icons from a local folder /img. I looked in some examples and all I could find are links from other servers. is there no way to load icons from a local folder like with widgets?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in the addon's 'data' folder and then get resource URIs for them using the self.data.url method. Here's an example add-on that references locally stored files and displays them as the widget icon and in a panel:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1030708/latest/